# Convert SQLDateTime DayTicks back to DateTime value

Tags: c#, sqldatetime

I have a date value stored as an integer in a database that was created using the SQLDateTime DayTicks function. How can I reverse engineer that integer value back into a DateTime value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will lose the time portion of the date unless you also have timeTicks floating around somewhere.  This will convert the dayTicks back into a DateTime:

```
SqlDateTime sdt = new SqlDateTime(dayTicks, 0);
DateTime dt = sdt.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime result = new DateTime(ticks);
```

There is an overload of the DateTime constructor that takes the number of ticks.

Comment: This will not work as expected if `ticks` is obtained from `SqlDateTime.DayTicks`.